# Trust me I'm a doctor - Origin of the phrase

Tags: etymology

Searching for the origin of the phrase, "Trust me I'm a doctor", which I take as a humorous way of simply saying, "Trust me!", it seems mostly to be attributed to the title of a British TV show of that name from 1996.

> The original series of the show ran for four series between 1996 and
> 1999.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_Me,_I%27m_a_Doctor_(TV_series)

However I have a strong feeling that the name of the TV show came from the expression rather than vice-versa.

Does anyone here have any proof (or anecdotal evidence) that predates 1996?

Comment: 1982 - https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Horseman_on_the_Roof/9OR9FbPO2RwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Trust+me+I%27m+a+doctor%22&pg=PA42&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @HotLicks, Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Hot Licks  - That link doesn't work perfectly for me. It takes me to a greyed-out page that is readable. I notice that it says this book was first published in 1951!

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica, 'Book' was published in 1951 but the 'history' it contains predates 1951.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul - Also, the book was a translation from French so did the translator invent the phrase? Actually on searching the text, I found the phrase "trust me" but not the full phrase so I'm not sure this is valid.

Comment: The problem with this is that the phrase almost certainly evolved from situations where it was simply an obvious thing to say. One notes the novel shows a person urging a drink on someone ill and citing his doctorate as a reason why the other person should trust his judgment in a medical matter.

Comment: Yeah, looking at the front of the book it says the original is from 1951, translation copyright 1953.

Comment: I have no documentary evedence but I'm sure I remember "trust me I'm a doctor" with a negative connotation from an American satirical comic that had found it's way into the UK in the late 60s. I also remember seeing the title of the show and feeling that the cynical comic connotations damaged its serious impact. It might just be me but a lot of these origin stories don't match with my personal feeling that the show title came from established usage rather than the other way round.

Comment: It probably originated the first time a doctor walked up to an ill or injured person and offered to help, and needed to allay suspicion.  In real life.

Comment: Perhaps related (or at least of interest): [I'm not a doctor, but I play one on TV](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/56279/who-originally-said-im-not-doctor-i-play-one-tv)

Answer (score 3):

[Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lippincott_s_Monthly_Magazine/_jYjAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22trust%20me%20i%27m%20a%20doctor%22&pg=PA744&printsec=frontcover) reports an occasion of the words in **Lippincott's Monthly Magazine** in 1894:

> "Dr. Tazewell was from home when the messenger arrived," he explained.
> "The case seemed urgent, so I took the liberty of coming in his stead.
> Mrs. Tazewell advised it. She'd been talking with an old woman who was
> excited about this child. You can trust me. I'm a doctor.”

Perhaps a harder question comes to mind: when did the words become a familiar expression with some sort of secondary meaning? That I don't know.

Comment: Doctors have traditionally been trusted with important things (like people's health including delicate and private matters, but also as a respected member of the community who may do things things like attesting to people's identity documents and signing people off work), so "trust me I'm a doctor" seems natural. Its extension might have a particular cause (e.g. a film or book) but might just be a natural feeling that a doctor is the most trustworthy person.

Comment: @Stuart F Yeah, I agree that there would be little fun in answering who first used some natural phrasing, like the expression "Please pass the salt." There seems to be some secondary meaning here that is the real interest in the problem. The original question suggested that the "I'm a doctor part" is irrelevant to the basic meaning, which is "Trust me." I would have thought that the humorous suggestion was that only a fool would trust someone simply because he is a doctor. But so far that seems to be just my take.

Answer (score -1):

From "Dirty Rotten Scoundrels", 1988, spoken by Micheal Caine's character.

http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/d/dirty-rotten-scoundrels-script-transcript.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).